# What is a solid approach to applying jQuery Mobile to a ReST styled MVC application?

Tags: rest, jquery-mobile, spring-mvc

I have an MVC application where all endpoints are simple ReST styled MVC endpoints that return static pages, i.e `/customers/${customerId}`, or for a customer listing `/customers?state=${state}`.

I'm adding mobile support through jQuery and am trying to establish a flexible design while fitting in with the rules of jQuery-mobile.

The first problem I face is that jqm is very much an ajax style UI framework where pages are loaded into the current document, or you build them all together. Given this I find it hard to see how static URI's would fit in, i.e. if I have `/customers/123` and `/customers/456` they are both the same view but different content, so should I then be controlling everything through ajax?

But then what if someone accesses the site via `/customers/789` instead of home and then navigating? How is this controlled if everything is done via ajax?

I would love to see a petclinic style example using spring and jqm.

Comment: yeah jquery mobile uses ajax navigation between pages, for my app I made simplified api on the server just for the mobile and echo json and update the app, regarding that access through some link that is tricky, you can put your logic code in one js file and include in every jquery mobile page, and when users enter the website with whatever link it will still load

Comment: Thanks abdu, if they access from whatever endpoint, how do you load that page? Do you have to inspect the URI and then open that view manually or is there some other trick?

Comment: yeah, on pageshow grab the ID and ajax the server and update the view, actually there was good answer here on SO, but I cant seem to find it, how to structure your app, Ill post the link here if I find it